# Choice of beam/beams for a car headlights

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, speech

When should we use *beam*, and when should we use *beams* for a car headlights? Here are some results I got from the Web:

Using "*put on*" and "*low beam(s)*":

> "Put on low beam" : *About **13,100** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on low beams" : *About **5,100** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on the low beam" : ***10** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on the low beams" : *About **19,500** results given by Google*

Using "*put on*" and "*high beam(s)*":

> "Put on high beam" : *About **49,900** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on high beams" : *About **29,300** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on the high beam" : *About **156,000** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on the high beams" : *About **95,800** results given by Google*

Using "*put on your*":

> "Put on your low beam" : *About **6** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on your low beams" : *About **2,370** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on your high beam" : *About **19,500** results given by Google*
>
> "Put on your high beams" : *About **11,600** results given by Google*

Using "*dip*" and "*high beam(s)*":

> "Dip high beam" : *About **6,360** results given by Google*
>
> "Dip high beams" : *About **896** results given by Google*
>
> "Dip the high beam" : *About **8,050** results given by Google*
>
> "Dip the high beams" : *About **13,300** results given by Google*

Using "*dip*" and "*your high beam(s)*":

> "Dip your high beam" : *About **1,030** results given by Google*
>
> "Dip your high beams" : *About **586** results given by Google*

Comment: Are you sure every result from Google exclusively relates to headlights?

Comment: No, not actually.

Comment: It's your choice.

Comment: We can hardly doubt Google’s statistics and my own experience discussing car lights here in the UK, in Zimbabwe and in Colorado is rather different.

The setting - of the switch and of the lights themselves - is normally referred to as *high beam*, singular.

Objects are normally seen in the *headlight beams*.

Perversely we might hear various constructions of *I couldn’t see enough with just the headlights so I put high beam on.*

In nearly 60 years on the road I've never noticed anyone use any of Google *Dip*s but I've heard hundreds of people say *Dip your lights*

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the singular form ("high-beam") is used as a modifier and to describe the setting itself, and the plural form ("low-beams") is used as a noun.

These examples are from Merriam-Webster (1):

1. The car's headlights were on high beam.
2. Turn off your high beams.

According to Wiktionary, it is "usually in the plural" (2).

**Sources**

1. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high%20beam
2. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/high-beam

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but could you explain how it answers the question, which was *When should we use beam, and when should we use beams for a car headlights?*

Comment: -1 I'm supposed to trust a statement (usually in the plural) in a "dictionary" written by amateurs who give no reference to support their claim?